# Unable to install XGBOOST on MAC using Anaconda

Tags: xgboost

I am using the Graphical Interface of Anaconda. I tried to install py-xgboost but it gave me the following error-
*UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:
Specifications:

- py-xgboost -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
  Your python: python=3.8
  If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
  When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
  not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
  change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
  that.*

It says I have python 3.8 installed in my system but when I checked the python version on my system using the command python2 --version & python3 --version it says I have python 2.7.16 & python 3.7.3

I dont have python 3.8

What shall I do now? The above python version were there already. I never installed and someone told me not to remove those versions as some of the MAC applications are dependent on them. Its a MAC BOOK PRO 15 ( 2019 )

Comment: This blogpost for xgboost/Anaconda install options may be of use to you: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/this-is-what-you-should-do-if-you-fail-to-install-the-latest-or-an-older-version-of-xgboost-on-7942a7641eee

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found a solution. I had to downgrade my python version.
But as explained above when I tried to check the version of python I am using I was getting 2.7 & 3.7.3 but my ANACONDA gives an error that I have version 3.8
That was because Anaconda uses the python which is installed in a separate directory, it was not using the python installed at the PATH directory. So I had to downgrade python which the ANACONDA was using by using the command -

```
conda search python
```

BTW if your terminal says conda command not found, then you need to edit your PATH first.

Then it gives a list of python version, you can then see which version is right for your XGboost version and then use the command-

```
conda install python=3.7.7
```

or whatever version you wanted to use.
After the downgrade of python, anaconda will ask you to downgrade other libraries as well, so go ahead and do that too unless you are using some command which was not there in the older version.

Now install py-xgboost from ANACONDA Graphical interface or by using conda method

```
conda install -c anaconda py-xgboost
```